# How to make and reference a configuration file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I have a file that I am trying to make a config.json file for to be able to input and change the data quick and easily. The code below is my mention.js file that I mapped and referenced into my index.js File. The data below needs to be changed periodically and and a config file that I can set the 1. accountName and 2. userId Into my mention.js file. I’m new to npm and JavaScript and am still learning so any help and advice would be extremely helpful. Thank you!!

````
const map = new Map();
map.set("Pogo0303PTA",'<@679533427925450852>');
map.set("Wretched0671pta", "<@679533427925450852>");
map.set("Pogo0347PTA", "<@679533427925450852>");
map.set("Wretched0047pta", "<@679533427925450852>");
map.set("PogoDroid","<@679533427925450852>");
module.exports = map;```
    
     ```{
"acct1": "pogopta000",
"userid1": "65465132168451324"
},
{
"acct2": {account}
"userid2": {userID}
} ETC...
````

Comment: So you are trying to make a basic configuration file, but do you want to be able to edit this file with a command, or only by manually changing the values?

Comment: by manually changing the commands. i was jsut wondering how i could make it so that i can simply edit the config file over having to change the mentiton.js file. basically i was wondering what i would type in my MAP or the index.js file to reference the config.json files data. basically in the config file i would have like my above edit

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to read the config.json file once, you can use `const config = require('./config.json')`, assuming you have the .js file in the same folder as config.json.

If you need to read config.json you can use node's built in module `fs` by putting `const fs = require('fs')` at the top of your program and using `let config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.json'))` to read the file, and using `fs.writeFileSync('./config.json', JSON.stringify(config))` to write the file.

You can structure your json file like:

```
   [
       {
            "accountName": "Pogo0303PTA",
            "userId": "<@679533427925450852>"
        },
        {
            "accountName": "Wretched0671pta",
            "userId": "<@679533427925450852>"
        },
        etc...
    ]
```

Hope this helped!